# Populate foreign collection in Hibernate based on two columns

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have an ITEM table and an ITEM_ASSOCIATION table.  ITEM_ASSOCIATION maintains groups of ITEMs that are related in some way, and contains the following columns: `item_id, group_id, type, value`. An example might be an article that represents the same content in 3 different languages:

```
id | item_id | group_id | type   | value
----------------------------------------
1    1234      1          'lang'   'en' 
2    2345      1          'lang'   'es'
3    3456      1          'lang'   'fr'
```

I have an Item and ItemAssociation Java Hibernate entities, and I want the Item class to contain a collection of ItemAssociation objects that belong to any groups that the Item is part of.  Example SQL for retrieving associations of Item 1234 would be:

```
select * from ITEM_ASSOCIATION 
where group_id in (select group_id from ITEM_ASSOCIATION where item_id = 1234)
```

Is there any way to represent that using standard Hibernate annotations? The ITEM_ASSOCIATION table is brand new, so I can change the schema/add new tables if need be to make it easier to work with Hibernate.  Also, our DB is Oracle if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item entity

```
@Entity 
public class Item {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
  private Set<ItemAssociation> associations;
}
```

ItemAssocation entity

```
@Entity
public class ItemAssociation {
  @EmbeddedId
  private ItemAssociationId id;
  @Column
  private String value;
  @JoinColumn(name = "itemId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Item item;
  @JoinColumn(name = "groupId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Group group;
}
```

ItemAssociationId primary key embeddable

```
@Embeddable
public class ItemAssociationId implements Serializable {
  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long itemId;
  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long groupId;
  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private String type;
}
```

Then in order to query for an item with all it's assocations, regardless of group:

> SELECT i FROM Item i JOIN FETCH ItemAssociation WHERE i.itemId = ?

Comment: I actually left out the "id" primary key column in the item_association table.  I'll give this setup a try, without the embedded id.

Comment: Also, Group is not a separate entity.  The group_id lives only in the ITEM_ASSOCIATION table, and is automatically incremented when a new group of associations is created.

Comment: @Jared understood and those implementation details won't affect the notion of how to issue the query between `Item` and `ItemAssociation`.